# Git best practice for modules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I switched my project to multiple sub repositories and included those repositories as git modules into main project.

This is my `.gitmodules` file:

```
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "packages/myproject-lib"]
    path = packages/myproject-lib
    url = git@git.example.com:rislab/myproject-lib.git
[submodule "packages/myproject-language-pack"]
    path = packages/myproject-language-pack
    url = git@git.example.com:rislab/myproject-language-pack.git
```

Every time I change something in one of the modules and check in these changes, in the main repository git shows some unstaged changes, like this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   packages/myproject-lib (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$
```

This pretty annoying although I kinda get why git is doing it. But since I'm the developer of the sub packages I don't really want git to tell me something changed in the projects gitmodules. This basically means I have to commit that change in case I want a clean status in my main project.

Is there a way to ignore the changes in gitmodules so my `git status` shows *everything is fine* in my main project?

I didn't find anything while ddg'ing (duckduckgoing) and also tried google. SO's suggesting also didn't point me to the correct answer.

Comment: There are many who would say that best practice for submodules is not to use them.

Comment: do not use submodules.